# How to add multiple roles to a user via office365 api?

Tags: office365, azure-ad-graph-api

I want add multiple roles to a user via office365 api at once.

But through the api which link is 
`https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directoryrole-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript`.

And I user the api as below

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/directoryRoles/{roleId}/members/$ref

Request Body(which type is [directoryObject][https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/directoryobject?view=graph-rest-1.0]):
{
  "id": "697c1e95-7184-45bc-a24b-2262b1b00bc7"
}
```

But the api return

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Request_BadRequest",
        "message": "An unexpected 'EndOfInput' node was found when reading from the JSON reader. A 'StartObject' node was expected.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "af3f38c5-bc87-4136-bae2-643c84a23281",
            "date": "2019-06-27T09:33:10"
        }
    }
}
```

I think there should be something wrong, but I can't find the problem.

Somebody can help? May be I use the wrong api?

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the Graph API documentation ([Add directory role member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directoryrole-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)), the POST body should be a odata link to the user.

[image]

I got a success as following:
[image]